Typescript - Get type of parameters from a function dynamically as key (param name) / value (type)
Is there a way to get every type of each params from a function? This must be dinamically generated.
Let's say we have:
type IFoo = {
  foo: (a: number, b: string) => void
}

And the output would be:
type IBar = {
  a: number,
  b: string
}

I have tried with the Parameters<T> but it returns only the types as values
type IFoo2 = Paramaters<IFoo['foo']>    // output: [a: number, b: string]


Nope! Not possible, the names are not visible to the type system, on purpose. See linked q/a for more information.
